# Mongoose update. How to update a document only for the difference

Tags: mongoose, http-post, updates

My question is based on POST requests for edits/updates. Using mongoose, how to update the target (document) only for the differences from the input as opposed to updating the entire document?

Assuming that the document in question (so does the input) has 100's of properties and If I want to update the target **only** for the **changed properties in my input**.. how can i do this in mongoose?

```
input:{
    fullname: "Full Name"
    nickName:"nick2", <----
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    100's of properties
} 

originalDocument:{
    fullname: "Full Name"
    nickName:"nick1", <----
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    100's of properties
}
```

Comment: If the others are unchanged then it shouldn't matter if they get updated with the same thing... You can use the findOneAndUpdate()

Comment: @SteveHolgado : Hmm. that makes sense. And by reading your comment, I am going to assume there is not(yet) a way to do this using mongoose!! Thanks for the suggestion though!